# Execute excel sum formula for every matching value in column

Tags: excel, sum, range, sumifs

I have the following data:

Column A: Employee Name . Column B: Role . Column C: Start Date

There are a number of other columns containing data related to each employee. I have a complex sum formula that I want to execute for every row where Role = "X", but I can't figure out how to execute for every instance in the column past the first match. I basically need `SUMIF($B:$B,"X",[sum_range])` where `[sum_range]` is my complex sum formula.

EDIT:
Below is my data. I want to apply my SUM formula only to the rows where, for example, Role = ASD. I can't use a SUMIF() formula to just lookup the matching role because I'm looking for more than just a simple sum.

[image]

Comment: Please show some example data so we can see what may be happening.

Comment: Is X actually being found in column B? have you tested that separately?

Answer (score 0):

In you example formula you are summing range B:B which you have stated above is role, you could use a sumifs statement which would allow multiple criteria, such as the below
[image]
=sumifs(sum_range,B:B,"role",A:A,"Employee")
This would sum the range for roles and employees that meet the criteria, you can replace role and employee with cells if these change across you Workbook.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add an IF statement to the code.

`IF(B2="ASD",[sum_range],"")`

And then drag it down to the bottom of you data.